# upgraded to roboelectric 4.0 and it gives dependency error

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, robolectric

upgraded to robolectric:4.0 and get error Module 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of [Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin)?